# Derselbige/Derselbe/Derjenige in genitive singular

Tags: pronoun, genitive, determiners

I observed that most masculine and neuter pronouns/pronominal determiners in genitive in singular form are declined by adding either **s** or **es** at the end of the word. However there are some that don't follow the trend. I managed to identify four determiners that are declined differently:

> dessen
>
> desselbigen
>
> desselben
>
> desjenigen
>
> (Genitive masc. Singular)

My question is, do I need to add the terminations specific to masculine/neuter nouns in genitive singular to the nouns that follow these pronominal determiners?

For example:

> desselben Mann**es**

Comment: In fact _derselb(ig)e_ and _derjenige_ **do** follow the standard in some way, if you consider them as pronoun + adjective: _desselben Mannes_ ~ _des selben Mannes_ ~ _des großen Mannes_, _derselbe Mann_ ~ _der selbe Mann_ ~ _der große Mann_.

Comment: In fact these can be seen as a contraction of an article and a pronoun, and because of the article we simply have weak inflection. So there is actually nothing special here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not for *dessen*.

> Das ist das Auto des Lehrers.
>   Und dieses ist das Auto desselben Lehrers.
>   Auch das ist das Auto desselbigen Lehrers.
>   Das ist das Auto desjenigen Mannes, der nur sonntags fährt.

*Dessen* is not followed by the genitive. It's a possessive relative pronoun. Here *Kofferraum* is nominative.

> Das ist das Auto, dessen Kofferraum nicht richtig schließt.

Comment: I assume it should read "*dessen* is **not** followed by the genitive"?

Comment: Thanks, corrected it.

Comment: I know this thread is old but I am not entirley sure about "dessen" not being used as a pronominal determiner. For example: "Der Herausgeber eines Buchs koordiniert und betreut **dessen** Veröffentlichung." Translation: The editor of a book coordinates and supervises **its** publication. And there is also a declension chart with demonstrative pronouns which includes **dessen**: https://www.verbformen.de/deklination/pronomen/der_dmo.htm#Steckbrief

Comment: That's true, but that's an entirely different context than above.